# Group by an aggregate function and subquery

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, group-by

Query and result snap:

[image: query and result snap]

Can somebody provide alternative query and explain the cause of error
and I tried alias name in group by but it still gives me same error.

Comment: Can you please add some sample data and expected result in text?

Comment: Remove `sum(s.fees)` from `Group by`. Also your `Group by` clause does not make lot of sense

Comment: You group by is not correct. You cant group and agreegate in same tame. Use subquery for this